# OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system in Django on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm using Django 2.0 and Heroku to host the application.

My media directory settings are like

**`App/settings/production.py`**:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static_cdn', 'media_root')
```

I'm using gTTS to convert text to speech and save `.mp3` file in the media directory:

```
tts_file_name = str(int(time.time())) + '.mp3'
joined_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'tts')
joined_path_with_file = os.path.join(joined_path, tts_file_name)

# create directory if does not exists
if not os.path.exists(joined_path):
    os.makedirs(joined_path)

tts = gTTS(text='Good morning', lang='en')
tts.save(joined_path_with_file)

# tts path to send to template
tts_media_url = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_URL, 'tts', tts_file_name)
```

It is working fine on local system as I can change file permissions manually also.

But It is not working on Heroku and giving error:

```
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/static_cdn'
```

I tried to locate `static_cdn` by running `heroku shell`, but could not even found `static_cdn` in application path and root path. But it seems to be working as other uploading through form is working perfectly.

using Django model's `upload_to` is working and even directory is created in `static_cdn`.

How can I create directory in `static_cdn` on Heroku the same way Django does using model's `upload_to`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changed `MEDIA_ROOT` path by removing additional `os.path.dirname()` and it is working now.

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_cdn', 'media_root')
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case, this error occurred because I set the `STATIC_ROOT = '/static/'`

This means it's looking at `/` root folder of the system and then `static`, which is obviously read-only,

changing it to `STATIC_ROOT = 'static/'` fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using `gTTS` to convert text to speech and save `.mp3` file in the media directory

I'm not sure what's causing your immediate error, but this isn't going to work very well on Heroku. [Its filesystem is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem): you can write to it, but whatever you write will be lost when the dyno restarts. This [happens frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting) (at least once per day).

[Heroku recommends using a third-party file or object store like Amazon S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3) for storing generated files, uploaded files, etc. I recommend gong down this path. There are [many Django libraries for using S3, and other services, as storage backends](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/storage-backends/).